# Merge two Lists. Sens of using HashSet

Tags: java, list, merge, hashmap

I found an algorithm containing a merge method (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/jacoco/org.apache.commons.math3.stat.clustering/DBSCANClusterer.java.html)

```
private <T> List<T> theirMerge(final List<T> one, final List<T> two) {
    final Set<T> oneSet = new HashSet<T>(one);
    for (T item : two) {
        if (!oneSet.contains(item)) {
            one.add(item);
        }
    }
    return one;
}
```

What is the main benefit of using a `HashSet` here?

My simpler implementation looks like this

```
private <T> List<T>  myMerge (ArrayList<T> one, ArrayList<T> two){
    for (T item: two) {
        if(!one.contains(item)){
            one.add(item);
        }
    }
    return one;
}
```

Comment: Dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035008/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-list

Comment: I know the difference. But why would I prefere to use the above version? Just to mix up the order?

Comment: because of performance (if order is not important), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706870/java-hashset-vs-array-performance

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid loops and use `addAll` method to merge two [set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) and avoid duplicates like:

```
oneSet.addAll(two);
```

While in list you are explicitly checking whether don't have an element in `list` and then only you are adding to the second list.

Comment: You mean creating two sets out of the lists, then calling addAll and then transforming it back to a list?

Comment: You already created `oneSet`, so add all elements from `two` to it and return that (or create another list of you want to return list).