# OCaml - If map is in standard OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, standards

I have a question. 
If Module Map is in standard OCaml ?
I cannot find answer in the internet.
Additionaly, what is difference between Map and Set?

Comment: You second question should be posted separately. It is entirely unrelated to the first question.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by "standard" OCaml. The compiler is distributed with a small library, and yes that does have a Map module. Its documentation is [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Map.html). This library is often called the "Standard Library", but there are actually two other libraries that are more comprehensive: [Batteries](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/) and [Core](https://github.com/janestreet/core). They both also have a Map module.

Comment: I think the term "standard library" is well-defined. Third-party libraries are not part of the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Map is a standard module in OCaml: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Map.html

To know the diff between map and set, you better have a look at [Difference between HashSet and HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773824/what-is-the-difference-between-hashset-and-hashmap)

Map in OCaml is like HashMap in Java, so does Set.

Comment: It's more like TreeMap and TreeSet in Java.

Comment: @newacct True, I just thought the OP even does not know what is Map and what is Set, so HashMap and HashSet are simpler to understand