# Creating XML from the data present in the dataSet

Tags: java, arrays, xml

1. I have the following data… in the form of Years and Months in my resultSet and I want to remove redundant years and months to create xml elements as:

   [2015, 2016, 2017]
   [05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 01, 02, 03, 04]

and I am trying to generate XML Tags out of this data Year and Month wise as:

```
<Root>
<Year Y="2015">
<Month M="05"/>
<Month M="06"/>
<Month M="07"/>
<Month M="08"/>
<Month M="09"/>
<Month M="10"/>
<Month M="11"/>
<Month M="12"/>
</Year>
<Year Y="2016">
<Month M="01"/>
<Month M="02"/>
<Month M="03"/>
<Month M="04"/>
<Month M="05"/>
<Month M="06"/>
<Month M="07"/>
<Month M="08"/>
<Month M="09"/>
<Month M="10"/>
<Month M="11"/>
<Month M="12"/>
</Year>
<Year Y="2017">
<Month M="01"/>
<Month M="02"/>
<Month M="03"/>
<Month M="04"/>
<Month M="05"/>
<Month M="06"/>
<Month M="07"/>
<Month M="08"/>
<Month M="09"/>
<Month M="10"/>
<Month M="11"/>
<Month M="12"/>
</Year>
</Root>
```

But the output I am getting is as:

```
<Root>
<Year Y="2015">
<Month M="05"/>
<Month M="06"/>
<Month M="07"/>
<Month M="08"/>
<Month M="09"/>
<Month M="10"/>
<Month M="11"/>
<Month M="12"/>
<Month M="01"/>
<Month M="02"/> 
<Month M="03"/>
<Month M="04"/>
</Year>
<Year Y="2016">
<Month M="05"/>
<Month M="06"/>
<Month M="07"/>
<Month M="08"/>
<Month M="09"/>
<Month M="10"/>
<Month M="11"/>
<Month M="12"/>
<Month M="01"/>
<Month M="02"/>
<Month M="03"/>
<Month M="04"/>
</Year>
<Year Y="2017">
<Month M="05"/>
<Month M="06"/>
<Month M="07"/>
<Month M="08"/>
<Month M="09"/>
<Month M="10"/>
<Month M="11"/>
<Month M="12"/>
<Month M="01"/>
<Month M="02"/>
<Month M="03"/>
<Month M="04"/>
</Year>
</Root>
```

That is how I am tackling my problem

```
try{
            //Connection
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(conUrl);
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

            //XML 
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();

            // Super Root Node (Necessity)
        Element necessaryElement = document.createElement("Root");
        document.appendChild(necessaryElement);

        while(resultSet.next()){
            //Year Array populating
            monitoringYear  = resultSet.getString("Year");
            monitoringYearArray.add(monitoringYear);

            //Month Array populating
            monitoringMonth = resultSet.getString("Month");
            System.out.println( "Monitoring Month "+ monitoringMonth);

            monitoringMonthArray.add(monitoringMonth);

        }

                    // remove duplicate from the Years ArrayList and retain the order
                Set<String> uniqueYearList = new LinkedHashSet<String>(monitoringYearArray);
                monitoringYearArray.clear();
                monitoringYearArray.addAll(uniqueYearList); 

                // Remove duplicate from the Month ArrayList and retain the order
                Set<String> uniqueMonthList = new LinkedHashSet<String>(monitoringMonthArray);
                monitoringMonthArray.clear();
                monitoringMonthArray.addAll(uniqueMonthList);

                    // XML Element for the Year
                for(int year = 0; year < monitoringYearArray.size(); year++){
                        // Super Root Node (Year)
                    Element yearElement = document.createElement("Year");
                    necessaryElement.appendChild(yearElement);

                    Attr yearAttr = document.createAttribute("Y");
                    yearAttr.setValue(monitoringYearArray.get(year));
                    yearElement.setAttributeNode(yearAttr);

                            // XML Element for the Month
                        for(int month = 0; month < monitoringMonthArray.size(); month++){

                                // Sub Root Node (Month)
                            Element monthElement = document.createElement("Month");
                            yearElement.appendChild(monthElement);

                            Attr monthAttr = document.createAttribute("M");
                            monthAttr.setValue(monitoringMonthArray.get(month));
                            monthElement.setAttributeNode(monthAttr);

                        }
                }
```

If you have any suggestions how to solve the problem, i would greatly appreciate
Thanks

Comment: if we look at the year 2015 Element... it has only 8 months starting from 5 and goes up to 12... that is where I am getting the problem. 2016 and 2017 has 12 months so i have am executing the loop for the size of month array which is 12 so it moves all the months up in the 2015 Tag..

Comment: Solved the Problem: needed to add this condition... if(monitoringMonthArray.get(month).equals("01") && monitoringYearArray.get(year).equals("2015") break;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is use of Set Object and while loop in one level that overwrites the months If you'd like to keep all the values a key is given, you might consider implementing like apache.commons.collections.MultiHashMap or

```
HashMap<String, LinkedHashSet> monthsincludedmap = new HashMap<String, LinkedHashSet >();
```

check 
[Difference between HashSet and HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773824/difference-between-hashset-and-hashmap)

[What happens when a duplicate key is put into a HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669885/what-happens-when-a-duplicate-key-is-put-into-a-hashmap)