# Why hashset solution is accepted whereas using hashmap getting timeout error-Finding pairs in array with difference K?

Tags: java, hashmap, timeout, hashset

I was going through a question where the problem was to find the number of pairs which makes a difference K.Below is the code for the same.In the below code I have used hashmap however it gave correct answer but for few of the scenario's I got timeout where as using HashSet all the test cases were passed.Can anyone help why using hashmap I am getting timeout error whereas in actual scenario hashmap computation is fast as compared to hashset.

```
static int pairs(int k, int[] arr) {

        HashMap<Integer,Integer> map=new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
            map.put(i,arr[i]);

        int count=0;
        for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++)
        {
            if(map.containsValue(arr[j]-k))
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Correct me if my understanding is wrong.Thanks in advance for the same.

Comment: Any specific reason to use `HashMap`? What is the amount of data?

Comment: Actually I thought the solution using hashmap initially but for few cases it failed that is when I went for hashset. Eager to know the reason of failure using hashmap. The size of an array is less than 10^5 and the values it can have 2^31-1.

Comment: Note that `containsValue` is O(n).

Comment: Can you add you code, using HashSet also. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Looking up a key in a HashMap is O(1)*, but looking up a *value* is O(n) -- it has to loop over every entry, one at a time, until it finds a matching value.

If you wanted analogous behavior to HashSet, you would need to put the things you've looking up into the keys, not the values. You would then use `containsKey`, and never actually care what there values are. Under the hood, that is in fact the [implementation of HashSet that OpenJDK uses](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashSet.java).

---

* it's actually a tad more complicated than that, but you can think of it as O(1) most of the time

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you can write the code this way & check:-

```
import java.util.*; 

class GFG { 

/* Returns count of pairs with 
difference k in arr[] of size n. */
static int countPairsWithDiffK(int arr[], int n, 
                                        int k) 
{ 
    int count = 0; 
    Arrays.sort(arr); // Sort array elements 

    int l = 0; 
    int r = 0; 
    while(r < n) 
    { 
        if(arr[r] - arr[l] == k) 
        { 
            count++; 
            l++; 
            r++; 
        } 
        else if(arr[r] - arr[l] > k) 
            l++; 
        else // arr[r] - arr[l] < sum 
            r++; 
    } 
    return count; 
} 


public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    int arr[] = {1, 5, 3, 4, 2}; 
    int n = arr.length; 
    int k = 3; 
    System.out.println("Count of pairs with given diff is " + 
                        countPairsWithDiffK(arr, n, k)); 
} 
}
```

> ***Time Complexity*: O(nlogn)**

Comment: Thanks for the help but I already have an accepted answer for the above problem using hashset. My concern is why using hashmap I was getting timeout.

Comment: This [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773824/difference-between-hashset-and-hashmap] would definitely help you! Just have a look once.